# Sublime text 2 convert html to javascript string

Tags: sublimetext2

I just started to use the trial of Sublime text 2 and was wondering if there is any function or plugin for me to convert block of HTML to javascript string ?

I have try to search but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue while reading this book, I am using WebStorm as Editor, and cannot find a way to perform that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime text doesn't perform any parsing/converting functions, it's just a very pretty and useful text editor with various syntax highlighting, and as far as I'm aware most plugins for it are either for visual styles/highlighting or version control, not converting from one thing to another.

Saying that, if you want to convert HTML to a Javascript style string try this: http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

Comment: Thanks, I have just started to read the book on Single Page Applications from Michael Mikowski and Josh Powell (ISBN-10: 1617290750) and wanted to follow the samples given. From one of the annotation, they state that a good Text editor to write js should provide a functionality to transform HTML to javascript string. 
But at the same time, after checking for a while on internet, I can see that people are happy developing js app using sublime text. Do you have any advice on that ?

Answer (score 0):

K. L., I am also reading this book and I gone through the same situation. I am using Notepad++ and could not find a way of doing this conversion directly from the editor. Then, I decided to download and install the vim editor (http://www.vim.org/download.php) and I made the configuration suggested by the authors on pages 73-74. It worked fine. Maybe I will try to make it work on Notepad++ in the future, but, for now, I can continue my reading. Hope this helps.

Comment: that does not solve problem in "sublime text editor 2".

Comment: You are right, @GaneshKamath. I should have answered as a comment on Jakob's answer. I tried, but I couldn't; the website didn't allow it, for I was a new user.